# Bluetooth has stopped working

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth has just stopped working. It's all been fine for about a year, then in the last week or two I was having trouble connecting to the bluetooth keyboard, (then the battery went in the mouse) and now the system has stopped being able find the controller.

I've had a look around and found a question on here about my problem but it didn't give an answer. I reinstalled bluez and it says I'm on the latest version

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

My USB bluetooth dongle is still plugged in like always

If if do `bluetoothctl` in the terminal it just says `'Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...'` and all I can do is quit terminal with this running